# Is it possible to send content body with get request in c# using HTTP 1.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to send content body with get request in c# using HTTP 1.1(RFC 2616). I also Need How to implement this in c#. I am getting protocol violation exception:can't send content body with this verb type.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, and it has nothing to do with C# or ASP.NET specifically.

Technically you *may* be able to include a request body in a GET request.  If certain objects in .NET don't allow you, you can always craft such a request manually and work around those objects.  However, that effort isn't going to get you very far, because GET requests aren't supposed to have request body content.  So the server is most likely going to ignore it anyway, if it's not dropped by something in between.

The bottom line is, GET requests don't have a request body.  Whatever you're trying to accomplish should be accomplished by some other means.

Comment: thanks David. But i need to implement this in my c# code. Is it possible using any nuget packages or third party tools.

Comment: @Dinesh: You're missing the point, this has nothing to do with C# code.  The HTTP protocol itself doesn't allow it.  It's not possible (or at least not reliable) with any package or third party tool.  What you *need* isn't to try to hack this together, what you *need* is to send data to the server in a different way.  If you can step back and clarify what you're trying to do I may be able to advise, but currently you're stuck in a flawed design and only asking how to implement that design, which isn't going to work.